# Installation solution needed

Tags: installation, cd

My old Dell was a speed demon back in the days of XP, but it has no DVD drive, no floppy and will not boot from USB. Is there another way to install Ubuntu or shall I gut the Dell and use the case as a flower pot?

Comment: Why do people insist in down-voting without any explanation?  I have no idea why you would down-vote this question anyway, was it unclear, off-topic, spam or un-researched?  Maybe you were too dense to get the humor included in the question?? It seems to me to be a valid question, even with research, the correct info is very hard to find on the Ubuntu website if you are a newbie....

Comment: agreed!!this question does matters  according to me to, might be some people feels its a joke .Well its just a situation when nothing is working and you need to intall ubuntu anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can connect to the internet, you can use the **network installer**.

You would need a decent connection but you should be able to use it

The link to get them is in this page, I am including the page as I'm not sure if you want 12.04 or 13.10:

[Alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

If your computer was an XP computer it may do better with a lighter weight Ubuntu desktop like Xfce or LXDE (the ones used in Xubunt or Lubuntu). The catch however, is that you will have to install the standard Ubuntu and then install the other desktops if you find that Unity is too slow for you as as far as I was able to determine, neither have network installers as an option.

Your computer may do fine running the standard Ubuntu, my old XP computer was able to handle Unity fine in 11.04 and 11.10.  I bought a new computer just before 12.04 came out so I can't say about the newer versions but it is likely that my old computer would still run fine.  Mine was not a top of the line XP model so if you have a very good XP computer as you question states then I think you will be ok with Unity, I was just including the info about Xfce and LXDE "just in case"

---

To add some more info, the network installer is not as simple as the LiveCD method so you should check out the install instructions(there is a lot of info here so be prepared for a long read)

[This is the install info for 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/)

[This is the install info 13.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/installation-guide/)

While I cannot help with the network install, there are a lot of user here and somone can help you if you are unsure about how to do it.  Just post another question about how to use the network installer and I think some kind soul will help you in short order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the network installer that will download and install the OS direct from inetrnet.

Else, you have to use an external CD/DVD rom and you can install using the standard installer.

Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) for more information about installation methods for Ubuntu